# pyspark temptable behaviour

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i wanted to achieve a functionality, i will have some BASE data, and i will get incremental data.

i will combine both and perform some operation(SQL query),on success i will have BASE = BASE + incremental for next run.

on exception my baseData will be BASE_Data(incremental should not be a part here).

I have tried explaining through the code below.

i am confused with the behavior of spark temp table...

```
# i am reading 2 files and persisting them in MEMORY_ONLY
df = spark.read.csv('BASE_data.csv', header=True)
df.persist()
print(df.count())  #o/p:4
df1 = spark.read.csv('data.csv', header=True)
df1.persist()
print(df1.count())  #o/p:4

# i will register temp tables
df.registerTempTable('BASE_data')
spark.sql('select count(1) from BASE_data').show()  # 4 which is fine
# i will append rows from df1 to df(BASE_data) and registered as combined_data
spark.sql("select * from {0}".format('BASE_data')).union(df1).registerTempTable('combined_data')
spark.sql('select count(1) from combined_data').show()  # 8 which is fine too

# Now i am going to unpersist df1 from memory and also change the variable
df1.unpersist()
df1=[]
spark.sql('select count(1) from combined_data').show()
# o/p=8, i am confused here, it should be 4
# when i unpersisted, spark might try to rebuild df1, by reading that file,
# so to be double sure, i reassign df1 to some empty list.
```

i need help here to understand this behavior and how can i achieve this functionality.

i am planning for the below simple approach, if there is any other approach

-- i donot want to keep BASE_data and Combine_DATA Status, can i achieve by having a single temp_table definition. spark.sql("select * from {0}".format('BASE_data')).union(df1).registerTempTable('BASE_data')

-- i donot want to create something that is going to be unused after sometime, and for execution will consume memory. BASE_data on exception should be fall back to original BASE_data i:e new additional data(df1) should be removed from BASE_data on exception or by unpersisting that.

please let me know if any thing is not clear, i will try my best to explain,  THANKS.

```
try:
    # create combine_data by union
    # do sql ops
    # BASE_DATA  = select * from cobine_data
except Exception:
    # BASE_data = BASE_Data # Basically do nothing
```

Also help me in "what kind of clean up i can do in the exception-Block for whatever(is ever) junk i might have created in Try-block ". I am really concerned about memory management. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You union df1 with df (which was registered in temp table named 'BASE_data') and then create a table with that data named combined_data. The method registerTempTable() is an action so at that time the DAG (directed acyclic graph) is evaluated (with the current values of df and temp_table 'BASE_data') so the data are copied in a different place in memory and are now independent from df1 and df. The delete of df1 at this point **has no effect** in the values in combined_data because they have already been evaluated.

I do not understand why you expect on the second count to get 4 instead of 8 which is the correct. The table is created on the line where you do the union and does not change from that time, so the result will not change.

Comment: My bad, i was not sure on "At that time the data are copied in a different place in memory". But i think as spark is lazy, why on declaration it goes to memory.

Comment: Spark is lazy until an action is triggered. Register as a table is an action, so at that exactly time everything is evaluated and copied in a different memory place.

Comment: Also if the answer was helpful please up vote and close the question

Comment: just one more concern here, if tempTable are taking place in memory, does that mean, if i have 2GB data, then on persist 2GB + on temp table 2GB i:e i will consume 4GB RAM memory ?? And if it is in memory then after registering temp table i can unpersist the dataframe to free up some memory, correct me here???  and in case of temp table how fault tolerance works?? it is too much of question that i asked, but i am very curious to know all these, if it is time taking, please give me some link to go through, that will suffice too. THanks very much for your help.

Comment: Your base logic is correct. When you register a table the data are saved in Hive's Columnar format which Add to dictionary significally reduces the memory consumption so even if your file is 2gB as a temp table it will be less. You can always check you memory when you do these operations to see how the various strategies affect memory consumption. Two considerations: Firstly registerTemTable is deprecated in Spark 2.0 so if you work in Spark 2.0+ use createOrReplaceTempView. Secondly you really need to consider why you want to persist the df. What do you gain with this?

Comment: If you gain indeed performance (you should test it though as I am not sure it gives you any boost in most scenarios) you can make the trade off with memory space. Also if memory crashes, for any reason, tempTables are lost so if you want fault tolerance you can use saveAsTable which creates a permanent physical table . See here for this method:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable

Comment: Yes, i really donot need  a df.persist(), But another drawback i can see in memory management perspective is SaveasTable and temptable are resulting in huge Shuffle writes when queried(simple selects with where clause and in groupby queries). Will try to reduce it(by exploring more on this shuffle reduction), Thanks for the great help though.